# Getting EntityNotFoundException for the existing ID in DB

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to create an Update Api in Java, But getting `EntityNotFoundException`.
Also my DB is already created through liquibase, So I'm bit confuse should I use DTO class or Entity Class.
Using Spring Boot 3.1.2 and jdk 17

**Entity Class**

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="og_student")
public class OgStudent{

    @Id
    private String ogStudentId;
    private String ogId;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    private String dob;

}
```

**RepositoryClass**

```
import com.fun.Studentmanagementservice.model.OgStudent;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface OgStudentRepo extends JpaRepository<OgStudent,String> {

}
```

**ControllerClass**

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class studentController {

    @Autowired
    private OgStudentRepo  ogStudentRepo ;

    @PutMapping("/update/{ogStudentId}")
   public ResponseEntity<String> updateStudent(@PathVariable String ogStudentId,@RequestBody OgStudent ogStudent){
        OgStudent existingStudent = orgStudentRepo.findById(ogStudentId).
                orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("OG Student not found"));

        if(existingStudent ==null){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        existingStudent .setFirstName(ogStudent.getFirstName());
        existingStudent .setLastName(ogStudent.getLastName());
        existingStudent .setMiddleName(ogStudent.getMiddleName());

        ogStudentRepo .save(existingStudent );
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Updated Successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is entity already present in the database?

Comment: @Prog_G Yes all the tables and columns are already there in DB, I dont have to create any new column or table

Comment: It might be because you're throwing it yourself: `orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("OG Student not found"));`. You are simply not getting a result for query by id.

Comment: I am talking about the record with id with which you are trying to update the record

Comment: @Prog_G Yes the id is existing in DB

Comment: If the record with the `id` does not exist then it will throw the exception. Could you verify if the record already exist in the table?

Comment: @Jorn But I'm trying for the ID which is alraedy existing in db

Comment: @Prog_G  using findById for a string type ID is correct?

Comment: can you try using `@Transactional` annotation on the `updateStudent` method?

Comment: @Prog_G I tried and still got the same error

Comment: @Prog_G I have ogStudentId within og_student table, still getting this error Actually I'm getting internal 500 server error as well

Comment: If it is not there, it is not there. What is the type of your column in the databasse?

Comment: @M.Deinum Mostly Varchar

Comment: @M.Deinum Ho my model or DTO class should look like it is creating new columns and I dont want that I already have them

Comment: Let me be more specific (I thought I already was) what is the type of the `ogStudentId` column? Please add your liquibase create script.

Comment: @M.Deinum orgStudentId is varchar(100) PK

Comment: Well then your id really doesn't match, it is a `String` so make sure that there are no trailing spaces (in both the db as well as the path variable), make sure encoding is correct as well as the casing.

Comment: @M.Deinum path variable? in entity class?

Comment: I'm getting the feeling you have no clue on what you are doing (sorry If I'm being blunt here) or how the technologies you are using actually work. The path variable is clearly in the controller (what do you think `@PathVariable` is), trim it before using it. Also when inserting data/creating data make sure you are trimming the id, if there are spaces, or there is a mismatch in case it will not match.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah I'm quiet new to this, I checked Path Variable and DB both have same name.

Comment: The names don't matter. It is about the **values**...

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to know what should I use DTO or Entity class for creating API in which we are not supposed to create any column, Only data need to be processed for update API, What should I use?

Comment: That is an opiniated question I'm not going to answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to use the built in spring data method, you should query as follows:

```
orgStudentRepo.findByOgStudentId(ogStudentId)
```

Comment: No you shouldn't if the column you are quering is the primary key, which it is in this case.

Comment: Could yo u please tell the reason why can't we query by primary key?

Comment: That is what `findById` does, your finder will generate a query instead of levering the `EntityManager.find` method. Next to that it will probably fail as there is no property named `ogStudentId` present only a primary key.

Comment: @M.Deinum But my ID is String, so does findById will be able to find String ID ?

Comment: What has the type to do with `findById`.... Why do you think `CrudRepository` takes 2 generic attributes? 1 for the type of entity and 1 for the type of the primary key.

Comment: @dracile can't you rename the ogStudentId to id? If yes, then you can leverage the findById method without creating the extra query.

Comment: @hermit I cannot change

Comment: Okay, so my above solution will create a extra query instead of reusing findById(). But, it returns the correct result. The field being  a primary key does not cause a problem. Could you please try?